# Use a canonical link and have the www version be master in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canonical-link

My site is both available as:

```
www.site.com
site.com
```

I want the www.site.com to be the primary site.  In case a user visits the naked site the header should have a canonical link to the www site.  Is there any easy way to do this in Rails?  I should be done for all pages from a certain controller.  (not all controllers since the site is multi tenant through subdomain: like client1.site.com etc...)

Comment: This should probably be done on the server level and not the application level. In both Apache and Nginx you should be able to redirect all requests without a subdomain to www. Doing it in Rails incurs a huge overhead.

Comment: @max I don't want to redirect requests...  I want to add a canonical link to the non-default page.  Otherwise I could do this through htaccess, DNS or Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This comment has been heavily edited upon clarification from the original poster**

To set a canonical link in Rails, you can use the `canonical-rails` gem: https://github.com/jumph4x/canonical-rails

Install the gem and then you can do:

```
rails g canonical_rails:install
```

Which will put a `canonical_rails.rb` file into `config/initializers`. Open that file and define your canonical url by adding this line:

```
config.host = 'www.yourapp.com'
```

Then, if you have an `app/views/layouts/layout.html.erb` file or similar, you can add:

```
<%= canonical_tag -%>
```

to the `<head`> portion of your view.

Comment: Hi, my question isn't about doing a redirect, I know how to do that.  I could also do a 301 to www.  
I want to add a canonical link so search engines know that the official page is the www.  although users can use whatever page they want.

Comment: @rept see my edited comment for a solution. Also, I might recommend editing your post to include SEO tags, or at least some references to it in your message body.